# Complying with Firebase auth rules

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm trying to build a simple web app that sends telemetry to Firestore. Every time a user takes an action, I want to call a function `updateUserWithAction` that sends data to Firestore, incrementing a count in /actions/{uid}. This is what I've got so far:

```
export const updateUserWithAction = async (user, action) => {                                        
  const userDocRef = doc(db, 'actions', user.uid)                                                    
  await updateDoc(userDocRef, {                                                                      
    action: increment(1)                                                                             
  });                                                                                                
};
```

This ran afoul of my security rules, since it's running on the client. I then tried to grant access to the client by offering this security rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /actions/{uid} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
```

This doesn't seem to be working, and I imagine that somehow I have to make the user authentication process (which is Firebase Auth) visible to Firestore...? Or do I have to pass the UID somewhere in `updateUserWithAction`? That doesn't make sense to me because it seems like a malicious user could send a made-up UID to enable themselves to update arbitrary records. So: how should I structure my app to enable writing to these records
securely?

Comment: If the user is signed in, there is nothing you have to "pass" at all. `request.auth.uid` in the rules will simply contain their uid.  But we can't see that they are signed in at the moment you make the query, nor can we see the value of `user.uid` in your code and that it matches the user's UID, so there's not much we can do to help without your specific debugging details showing those values.

Comment: ah okay, that's really interesting and helpful. Let me try to get those values for you!

Comment: @DougStevenson if you give that as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is signed in, there is nothing you have to "pass" at all. `request.auth.uid` in the rules will simply contain their uid. But we can't see that they are signed in at the moment you make the query, nor can we see the value of `user.uid` in your code and that it matches the user's UID, so there's not much we can do to help without your specific debugging details showing those values.